# Saving Mann Kendall output results in excel

Tags: r, statistics

Here is the code I am using for the Mann Kendall test. but I am unable to save its output results in Excel

```
Prec_45<- mk.test(data$Prec_45_BC)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to save the Z statistic and p-value of Mann Kendall test. You can use the following code

```
library(trend)
library(openxlsx)

data(Nile)
z_statistic <- mk.test(Nile)$statistic
p_value <- mk.test(Nile)$p.value

write.xlsx(cbind.data.frame(z_statistic, p_value), "MK_output.xlsx")
```